# Query Paramteters not being set properly in Spring

Tags: spring

So  I have the ff. code to set headers and query parameters

```
public final RequestEntity<String> make(final Optional<String> cursor) {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Username", this.credentials.getUsername());
        headers.add("Password", this.credentials.getPassword());

        final UriComponentsBuilder body = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .queryParam("record_limit", this.recordLimit.toString())
                .queryParam("cif", this.cif)
                .queryParam("account_type", this.accountType)
                .queryParam("account_status", this.accountStatus.getCode());

        cursor.ifPresent(
                cur -> body.queryParam("cursor", cur)
        );

        return new RequestEntity<>(
                body.build().getQuery(),
                headers,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                URI.create(this.url)
        );
    }
```

This code gives an error on my side since the query parameters are not being set properly, instead of a ? in the request URI, it has a , (comma) instead [see screenshot below]

[image]

Trying it on my curl/postman app with a comma, I could indeed replicate the error if I replace it with a comma from its intended query format with a ? (question mark), what do I do to fix this query params issue?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UriComponentsBuilder` is a helper class to build a URI components. Don't use it to create request body.

You can create the URI either like this

```
final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .scheme("http")
                .host("www.your-domain.com")
                .path("/esb/service/CommunicatorGateway/customer/accountlist")
                .queryParam("record_limit", this.recordLimit.toString())
                .queryParam("cif", this.cif)
                .queryParam("account_type", this.accountType)
                .queryParam("account_status", this.accountStatus.getCode());
```

or like this,

```
final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl("http://www.your-domain.com/esb/service/CommunicatorGateway/customer/accountlist")
                .queryParam("record_limit", this.recordLimit.toString())
                .queryParam("cif", this.cif)
                .queryParam("account_type", this.accountType)
                .queryParam("account_status", this.accountStatus.getCode());
```

Then finally create your `RequestEntity` like this,

```
return new RequestEntity<>(
                null,
                headers,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                uriBuilder.build().encode().toUri()
        );
```